# Debug javascript in Visual Studio 2012 when using chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to debug javascript code in visual studio when using chrome or firefox? With IE it works, but also when i enabled source maps in chrome it does not work.

In webstorm it works by the way so it is technically possible in general.

Comment: Why don't you debug with devtools in chrome or firebug in FF?

Comment: it is easier to debug the code where i write it IMO

Comment: It is also possible in NetBeans (at least with Chrome).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is: it is not possible